# Using FFMPEG libs to UDP stream mpeg2 ts video delay / initial connection problems

Tags: c++, video, ffmpeg, libavcodec, libavformat

Currently using the lib's from FFPMEG to stream some MPEG2 TS (h264 encoded) video. The streaming is done via UDP multicast.

The issue I am having currently is two main things. There is a long initial connection time / getting the video to show (the stream also contains metadata, and that stream is detected by my media tool immediately).

Once the video gets going things are fine but it is always delayed by that initial connection time.

I am trying to get as near to LIVE streaming as possible.

Currently using the av_dict_set(&dict, "tune", "zerolatency", 0) and "profile" -> "baseline" options.

GOP size = 12;

At first I thought the issue was an i frame issue, but the initial delay is there if gopsize is 12 or default 250. Sometimes the video will connect quickly, but it is immediately dropped, the delay occurs, then it starts back up and is good from that point on.

According to documentation the zero latency option should be sending many i frames, to limit initial syncing delays.

I am starting to think its a buffering type issue, as when I close the application and leave the media player up, it then fast forwards through the delay till it hits basically where the file stops streaming.

Answer (score 0):

So while I don't completely understand what was wrong, I at least fixed the problem I was having.

The issue came from using the av_write_interleaved_frame() vs. the regular av_write_frame()(this one works for live streaming), when writing out the video frames. Ill have to dig into the differences a bit more to fully understand it, but its funny sometimes how you figure out the problem you are having on a total whim after bashing your face for a few days.

I can get pretty good live ish video streaming with the tune "zerolatency" option set.

Comment: Well, interleaved write attempts to organize the packets internally to keep them in sync. The delay could have been caused by the internal buffering and re-ordering that FFMPEG does. On another note, could you update your question to elaborate on how you did the streaming with FFMPEG? I am interested in doing this with FFMPEG but I have very very minimal FFMPEG experience.